# flex blazeds spring jpa hibernate under eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, hibernate, spring, jpa

I'm looking for a tutorial where the following technologies: flex blazeds spring jpa hibernate  are use into  eclipse to create a Java EE web dynamic project.

- I wish that the jpa and hibernate will be auto-generated by an orm plugin (such as hibernate tools, or other one).
- the dao and dto will be both implemented in this architecture.
- and why not using the springsource tools suite under eclipse.
  I'm working with the eclipse galileo SR2, mysql as database and tomcat, but for the two last technolgies other ones are welcome.

Comment: I voted to close as this is too general.  If you are having specific problems with any of this, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, this is a very general question.  Try this [tutorial](http://www.jamesward.com/2009/04/06/download-the-flex-and-spring-integration-refcard/) though, it will help you with Flex and Spring integration.